# In a form, I need to populate the contents of same spreadsheet column like 50 times. Is there a way to script this logic with fewer iterations

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dry, google-forms

I'm working on a form where I need to pull the contents of a spreadsheet column like 50 times, to try to input multiple items from a list. I see that I can do this by defining a few variables and redoing a small piece of Script again and again. I want to see if anyone can help me overcome this lengthy script to make it smaller with fewer iterations. Thanks.

```
function updateForm(){
  // call the form and connect to the drop-down items
  var Form_SQ = FormApp.openById("FORM ID");
  var SQ_IT01_List = Form_SQ.getItemById("ITEM 01").asListItem();
  var SQ_IT02_List = Form_SQ.getItemById("ITEM 02").asListItem();
  //Similarly defining upto 50 dropdown lists.


  var SS01 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var SQ_IT01_Names = SS01.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var SQ_IT02_Names = SS01.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  //Similarly defining upto 50 names lists.


  // Item_01 Part Number Dropdown
  var SQ_IT01_Values = SQ_IT01_Names.getRange(2, 1, SQ_IT01_Names.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
  var SQ_IT01_Items = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < SQ_IT01_Values.length; i++)
  if(SQ_IT01_Values[i][0] != "")
  SQ_IT01_Items[i] = SQ_IT01_Values[i][0];
  SQ_IT01_List.setChoiceValues(SQ_IT01_Items);

  // Item_02 Part Number Dropdown
var SQ_IT02_Values = SQ_IT01_Names.getRange(2, 1, SQ_IT02_Names.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
  var SQ_IT02_Items = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < SQ_IT02_Values.length; i++)
  if(SQ_IT02_Values[i][0] != "")
  SQ_IT02_Items[i] = SQ_IT02_Values[i][0];
  SQ_IT02_List.setChoiceValues(SQ_IT02_Items);

  //Similarly defining upto 50 lookup lists.

}
```

Comment: Try a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

Reusing code and making use of loops. Scripting is all about efficiency (see [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle): make as little assignments and same-functionality coding as possible - use loops, move reusable code snippets to functions that can be called on demand, etc.

**Solution**

This sample makes several assumptions:

1. `SQ_IT01_Names` is different for each item (in your sample it always is `Sheet2` - if this is the case, you don't have to reassign it 50 times, one variable assignment will do just fine).
2. You intended to do something when a value is an empty string (the sample just filters them out). As you use the `[index]` notation, those values in the resulting `Array` will be `undefined` (and that's not something one would want in an `Array` of choice values).
3. All items are choice items (if you need id filtering, the sample is easily expanded).

---

```
function updateForm() {
  var form = FormApp.openById("FORM ID");

  //access every item;
  var items = form.getItems();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  //loop over items;
  items.forEach(function(item,i){
    var namesSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet'+i); //assuming this is diff each time;
    var namesRange = namesSheet.getRange(2,1,namesSheet.getLastRow());
    var namesValues = namesRange.getValues();

    //map values to first column;
    namesValues = namesValues.map(function(value){
      return value[0];
    });

    //filter out undefined (undefined and false functional equivalence);
    namesValues = namesValues.filter(function(value){
      return value;
    });

    item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(namesValues);
  });
}
```

---

**Notes**

1. Please, use closures `{}` with loops and `if` statements, this way you'll be able to keep track of which statements are enclosed in it and save yourself debugging time when looping / conditioning multiple statements.
2. Since you only need rows that have data in them, use the `getLastRow()` method instead of the `getMaxRows()-1` calc you have to perform in your script.

**Reference**

1. `forEach()` method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach);
2. `filter()` method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter);
3. `map()` method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map);
4. `getLastRow()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow);